# Flutter doesn't show icon

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter and I still have a way to go. I have problem in the `Home()` class that the two `iconButtons` that I have created only show a box with an x in the middle.

I have already checked the `pubspec.yaml` file and the material design is set on true so I'm a bit lost.

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Image.asset("assets/al_servicio_logo.png"),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 35, 129, 163),
      ),
      body: CardExample(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        color: const Color.fromARGB(235, 35, 129, 163),
        height: 60,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.account_circle_rounded),
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting the app? Your code runs fine on my machine with the icons showing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these:

1. Delete the app from your emulator or physical device
2. Run `flutter clean`
3. Reinstall the app